How does the rpart package get the "improve" when there is “ missing”?
library(mlbench)
library(rpart)

data(Sonar)

Sonar[1,"V11"] <- NA
ct1 <- rpart(Class ~ .,data = Sonar , method = "class", cp = 0) 
summary(ct1)


How does the rpart package get the "improve=27.13488" when there is “1 missing”?
